# How to refresh token with Ktor Oauth?

Tags: ktor

I've setup an oauth autorization using Ktor Oauth like in the example https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/blob/1.3.0/feature/auth/src/io/ktor/samples/auth/OAuthLoginApplication.kt

I'v got oauth token, but how to refresh it after expiration time?

Comment: There's a YouTrack issue that might help you.  It doesn't look like it is supported out of the box right now.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-331